# Multi-column RMarkdown pdf with tables: "! Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode."

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

Is it possible to knit an `.rmd` into a multi-column `.pdf` when the RMarkdown file contains Markdown tables? I am trying to make a very compact (small font, minimal spacing, etc.) pdf to use a formula sheet, but I can't print the `.rmd` into a multi-column pdf when it contains Markdown tables. Is there a way around this error?

```
---
title: ""
output:
  pdf_document
classoption:
- twocolumn
---

# Introduction

    | Model                                 | Formula                                                                               |
    | :------------------------------------ | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
    | Intercept Only                        | $\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \beta_{0} + \epsilon_{i}$                                     |
    | Simple linear regression              | $\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$                    |
    | Multiple linear regression            | $\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x'_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$                   |
    | Interaction/Moderation                | $\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_1{i} + \beta_{2}x_2{i} + \epsilon_{i}$ |
```

RStudio errors:

```
> ! Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.

> Error: LaTeX failed to compile reprex.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See repre.log for more info.
> Execution halted
```

Error from `reprex.log`:

```
> ! Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.
```

Comment: I don't get a longtable if you just copy and paste the code from your question ...

Comment: ... that being said, you don't seem to have any r specific code in your table. Instead of a markdown table, you could simply add a proper latex `tabular`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have any r specific code in your table. Instead of a markdown table, you could simply add a proper latex tabular:

```
---
title: ""
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
classoption:
  - twocolumn
---

# Introduction

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Model                                 & Formula                                                                               \\
\hline
Intercept Only                        & $\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \beta_{0} + \epsilon_{i}$                                     \\
Simple linear regression              & $\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$                    \\
Multiple linear regression            & $\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x'_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$                   \\
Interaction/Moderation                & $\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_1{i} + \beta_{2}x_2{i} + \epsilon_{i}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with my huxtable package:

````
---
title: ""
output:
  pdf_document
classoption:
- twocolumn
---

Two-column text goes here...

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(huxtable)
ht <- tribble_hux(
  ~Model, ~Formula,
  "Intercept only", "$\\operatorname{Y_{i}} = \\beta_{0} + \\epsilon_{i}$"
)

# to allow printing maths in column 2:
escape_contents(ht)[, 2] <- FALSE

ht

```

More two-column text goes here...
````

You may also be interested in `position(h) <- "wrapleft"`, and other properties like `font_size` and `width`.